# Manipulating numbers inside text file / storing them in pointers in C

Tags: c, file, text

Hello and good day to all of you. I've encountered a problem which I've spent a good 3 hours on, not finding a solution. I want to extract data from a text file and and put it in different pointers that have corresponding names.

For example : QUA_1 goes in qua1, etc...

Everytime I launch the code, I get the "wntdll.pdb not loaded".

The text file's layout is as such :

```
Syntax version=4
Wed Mar 17 12:26:34 2021
Starting process (10000000 clocks per sec)

LogRawData=false
VarHeader=1
D:      Accelerometer_1[0]  Accelerometer_2[0]  Gyroscope_1[0]  Gyroscope_2[0]  QUA_1[0]    QUA_2[0]    Accelerometer_1[1]  Accelerometer_1[2]  Accelerometer_2[1]  Accelerometer_2[2]  Gyroscope_1[1]  Gyroscope_1[2]  Gyroscope_2[1]  Gyroscope_2[2]  QUA_1[1]    QUA_1[2]    QUA_1[3]    QUA_2[1]    QUA_2[2]    QUA_2[3]
D:  time(ms)    (0x200000b8,5)  (0x20000054,5)  (0x20000048,5)  (0x20000060,5)  (0x20000028,5)  (0x200000a8,5)  (0x200000bc,5)  (0x200000c0,5)  (0x20000058,5)  (0x2000005c,5)  (0x2000004c,5)  (0x20000050,5)  (0x20000064,5)  (0x20000068,5)  (0x2000002c,5)  (0x20000030,5)  (0x20000034,5)  (0x200000ac,5)  (0x200000b0,5)  (0x200000b4,5)
D:  0.31    -685    -670    16  2   1529    8263    -549    445 -707    81  -3  12  10  -19 -7221   -4455   13932   -10991  -795    8873
D:  2.96    -685    -670    16  2   1529    8263    -549    445 -707    81  -3  12  10  -19 -7221   -4455   13932   -10991  -795    8873
D:  5.46    -685    -670    16  2   1529    8263    -549    445 -707    81  -3  12  10  -19 -7221   -4455   13932   -10991  -795    8873
D:  7.91    -685    -670    16  2   1529    8263    -549    445 -707    81  -3  12  10  -19 -7221   -4455   13932   -10991  -795    8873
D:  10.65   -685    -670    16  2   1529    8263    -549    445 -707    81  -3  12  10  -19 -7221   -4455   13932   -10991  -795    8873
D:  13.64   -685    -670    16  2   1529    8263    -549    445 -707    81  -3  12  10  -19 -7221   -4455   13932   -10991  -795    8873
D:  16.42   -685    -670    16  2   1529    8263    -549    445 -707    81  -3  12  10  -19 -7221   -4455   13932   -10991  -795    8873
D:  18.89   -714    -680    8   4   1531    8263    -543    460 -735    81  24  3   -9  0   -7217   -4458   13933   -10991  -795    8873
D:  21.55   -714    -680    8   4   1531    8263    -543    460 -735    81  24  3   -9  0   -7217   -4458   13933   -10991  -795    8873
D:  24.03   -714    -680    8   4   1531    8263    -543    460 -735    81  24  3   -9  0   -7217   -4458   13933   -10991  -795    8873
D:  26.49   -714    -680    8   4   1531    8263    -543    460 -735    81  24  3   -9  0   -7217   -4458   13933   -10991  -795    8873
D:  29.03   -714    -680    8   4   1531    8263    -543    460 -735    81  24  3   -9  0   -7217   -4458   13933   -10991  -795    8873
D:  31.49   -714    -680    8   4   1531    8263    -543    460 -735    81  24  3   -9  0   -7217   -4458   13933   -10991  -795    8873
D:  33.97   -714    -680    8   4   1531    8263    -543    460 -735    81  24  3   -9  0   -7217   -4458   13933   -10991  -795    8873
```

Note : there are more lines in the text file but all of them are similar to the "D: ..." lines apart from the numbers changing.

As for the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_BLOCK_SIZE 100
uint32_t MAX_INDEX = MAX_BLOCK_SIZE - 1;

.
.
.

void getData(double* time_t, uint32_t** acc1, uint32_t** acc2, uint32_t** gyro1, uint32_t** gyro2, uint32_t** qua1, uint32_t** qua2)
{
    /******************* TEMPORARY SECTION *******************/
    // char ch;
    FILE* fichier;
    errno_t err = 1;

    while (err == 1)
    {
        // Open the file in READ mode ==> avoid modifying the data
        err = fopen_s(&fichier, "Dan_AHAHAHHAHA.txt", "r");

        //perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
    }

    // Keep going until you reach the end of the document
    //while ((ch = fgetc(fichier)) != EOF)
    //  printf("%c", ch);

    uint32_t i = 0;
    //uint32_t indice_phase1 = 0;

    // Data processing loop
    while (feof(fichier) != 1)
    {
        // fseek allows to get each line separately
        fseek(fichier, 3, 0);

        // Then, we get the values from the line and separate them into their corresponding pointers
        fscanf_s(fichier, "%lf%lu%lu%lu%lu%lu%lu%lu%lu%lu%lu%lu%lu%lu%lu%lu%lu%lu%lu%lu%lu",
            &time_t[i], &acc1[0][i], &acc2[0][i], &gyro1[0][i], &gyro2[0][i], &qua1[0][i], &qua2[0][i],
            &acc1[1][i], &acc1[2][i], &acc2[1][i], &acc2[2][i], &gyro1[1][i], &gyro1[2][i], &gyro2[1][i],
            &gyro2[2][i], &qua1[1][i], &qua1[2][i], &qua1[3][i], &qua2[1][i], &qua2[2][i], &qua2[3][i]);
        i++;

        // when there's no more space in the pointers, they need to be reallocated to bigger pointers
        if (i == MAX_INDEX)
        {
            IncreaseTimeSize(time_t, MAX_INDEX);
            Increase_GyroAccelero_Size(acc1, MAX_INDEX);
            Increase_GyroAccelero_Size(acc2, MAX_INDEX);
            Increase_GyroAccelero_Size(gyro1, MAX_INDEX);
            Increase_GyroAccelero_Size(gyro2, MAX_INDEX);
            IncreaseQuaternionSize(qua1, MAX_INDEX);
            IncreaseQuaternionSize(qua2, MAX_INDEX);
            MAX_INDEX += MAX_BLOCK_SIZE;
        }
    }

    // Deallocate excesse dynamic memory to the system for better performance
    ResizeQuaternionSize(qua1, MAX_INDEX, i);
    ResizeQuaternionSize(qua2, MAX_INDEX, i);
    Resize_GyroAccelero_Size(acc1, MAX_INDEX, i);
    Resize_GyroAccelero_Size(acc2, MAX_INDEX, i);
    Resize_GyroAccelero_Size(gyro1, MAX_INDEX, i);
    Resize_GyroAccelero_Size(gyro2, MAX_INDEX, i);
    Resize_Time_Size(time_t, MAX_INDEX, i);

    fclose(fichier);

    /******************* TEMPORARY SECTION *******************/
/*************** Part 2 : Quaternion Normalisation ***************/

    double norme_qua1 = 0;
    double norme_qua2 = 0;

    for (uint8_t j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        norme_qua2 = sqrt(pow(qua2[0][j], 2) + pow(qua2[1][j], 2) + pow(qua2[2][j], 2) + pow(qua2[3][j], 2));
        norme_qua1 = sqrt(pow(qua1[0][j], 2) + pow(qua1[1][j], 2) + pow(qua1[2][j], 2) + pow(qua1[3][j], 2));
        qua1[0][j] = qua1[0][j] / norme_qua1;
        qua1[1][j] = qua1[1][j] / norme_qua1;
        qua1[2][j] = qua1[2][j] / norme_qua1;
        qua1[3][j] = qua1[3][j] / norme_qua1;

        qua2[0][j] = qua2[0][j] / norme_qua2;
        qua2[1][j] = qua2[1][j] / norme_qua2;
        qua2[2][j] = qua2[2][j] / norme_qua2;
        qua2[3][j] = qua2[3][j] / norme_qua2;
    }
}
```

The "resizing" and "increasing" function have about the same layout as the one below :

```
/********************************************************************************************\
|*                  Resize pointers for Accelerometers and Gryscopes                        *|
|* This function is for deallocating excess memory from the pointers containing the data    *|
|* retrieved from the patient or file. This one's for triple pointers on the uint32_t type. *|
\********************************************************************************************/

void Resize_GyroAccelero_Size(uint32_t** name, uint32_t max_index, uint32_t size)
{
    /*
     * The Realloc function can FAIL!!! Thus, it is MANDATORY to use a temporary variable
     * and reallocate in cas of failure. If not, data can be OVERWRITTEN, and the data
     * processing will be wrong, resulting in wrong moves!!!
     */

    // Create temporary variable
    uint32_t** tmp = (uint32_t**)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t*) * 3);

    // While memory is not allocated...
    while (&tmp == NULL)
    {
        // Print in the console if an error occurs
        perror("realloc-*time");

        // Create temporary variable until memory is allocated...
        uint32_t** tmp = (uint32_t**)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t*) * 3);
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            *tmp[i] = (uint32_t)realloc(*name, size * sizeof(uint32_t));
    }
    *name = (uint32_t*)tmp;  /* now assign the reallocated block to your pointer */
}

void Increase_GyroAccelero_Size(uint32_t** name, uint32_t max_index) // slightly changed to test
{
    /*
     * The Realloc function can FAIL!!! Thus, it is MANDATORY to use a temporary variable
     * and reallocate in cas of failure. If not, data can be OVERWRITTEN, and the data
     * processing will be wrong, resulting in wrong moves!!!
     */

    // Create temporary variable
    uint32_t** tmp = (uint32_t**)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t*) * 3);

    // While memory is not allocated...
    while (&tmp == NULL)
    {
        // Print in the console if an error occurs
        perror("realloc-*time");

        // Create temporary variable until memory is allocated
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            *tmp[i] = (uint32_t)realloc(*name, (max_index + 1 + MAX_BLOCK_SIZE) * sizeof(uint32_t));
    }
    *name = (uint32_t*)tmp;  /* now assign the reallocated block to your pointer */
}
```

Do not mind the agressive commenting I've been doing, my teachers like it this way.

Comment: " I want to extract data from a text file and sort it out and put it in different pointers that have corresponding names."  - That description is unclear, almost to the extent of being meaningless.

Comment: "// fseek allows to get each line separately"`fseek(fichier, 3, 0);` I don't see how that gives you a new line?

Comment: Nevermind this wrong comment, it is to skip the "D: " part at the beginning of each line I think. Not to sure though, since it is "translated" code from matlab.

Comment: You are using `feof` incorrectly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: That is not what `fseek` does.  `fseek(fichier, 3, 0);` will either move you to the 3rd byte of the file, (attempt to) move 3 bytes past the end of the file, or move 3 bytes past the current location.  You should never use `0`: use SEEK_SET, SEEK_END, or SEEK_CUR.

Comment: Almost certainly, SEEK_SET is 0, so your fseeks are always moving you to the 3rd byte of the file. (Or they are failing; you should check).

Comment: Thanks for this information William. I will look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary loop is wrong.  There is no need for `fseek` here, and it is being used incorrectly.  `fseek` knows nothing about lines; it will position the file pointer in the byte stream relative to the beginning of the file, the end of the file, or the current position.  Also, the present usage of `feof` is incorrect.  (See [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong))

You should change your main loop to look something like:

```
    while( 21 == fscanf(fichier, "D: %lf %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu ... ",
        time_t + i, acc1[0] + i, ... ) ){ ... }
```

Note that the spaces in the format stream are purely cosmetic.  They won't change how `fscanf` works, but they make the code a lot easier on the eyes.  You can use `fscanf_s` if you prefer, but it's non-standard and I've modified the answer to use the standard function.

Comment: Ok! Now it does not give me the error but an exception is lifted at this line : 
`norme_qua2 = sqrt(pow(qua2[0][j], 2) + pow(qua2[1][j], 2) + pow(qua2[2][j], 2) + pow(qua2[3][j], 2));`

Do you happen to know why?

Comment: I would guess perhaps one of those `sqrt` has a negative value passed.  But that's just a guess.

Comment: After a few tests, it seems like the pointers are null, since they contain the 3452816845 number, which I guess means they not initialized. Still looking into the matter.